# Typography of sideways figure

Tags: floats, page-numbering, typography, rotating

Since my figure is too wide to fit the layout, I rotate it using `sidewaysfigure` environment from `rotating` package. I'd like to clear out some typographical issues with respect to international and/or Czech typographical norms or conventions.

- Should the caption of the figure also be rotated (as sidewaysfigure does)? I assume it should.

  What about page number? Should it be put sideways or not or should it disappear completely since this is a special page?

Since this question may be off-topic as suggested in comments, I asked also on Graphic Design SE: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/35583/typography-of-sideways-figure

Comment: Ahoj! :) I'm afraid that this question is off-topic since it doesn't ask _how_ to do something, rather it asks _what_ to typeset, and it is therefore not directly related to the TeX world. As for my opinion, I usually don't rotate the caption, and I wouldn't remove the page number, as far as scientific publications are concerned.

Comment: @tohecz Ahoj :-) I viewed the questiong tightly connected to typesetting in TeX. Also in a certain way I know \emph{what} to typeset – I want to put my figure to the document – but I don't know \emph{how} to resolve the problem it doesn't fit into the layout. If the question if off-topic, where to put it? I couldn't find typography group on SE.

Comment: Maybe for these people: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/typography

Comment: As you've asked on GraphicDesign, I've simply closed here. I could have migrated the question, but there's little point as they'll just merge with the one there!